# Accessing EKS service privately within AWS infra

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a service in K8S which I want to access from another EKS cluster's POD privately.

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: test
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8888
```

In LoadBalancer's Security Group I have removed `0.0.0.0/0` and enabled only client's worker node IP and POD IP

Worker Node IP

```
Type: All traffic
Protocol: All   
Port range: All 
Source: 10.x.0.0/16
```

POD IP

```
Type: All traffic
Protocol: All
Port range: All
Source: 10.x.x.x/32
```

Now when I telnet to the service from the client's POD, telnet hangs at Trying state

```
telnet xxxx-xxxxx.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com 80
Trying xx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
```

If I enable all source in security group like below, everything works fine. Which is not intended behavior because this resource must be accessed privately.

```
Type: HTTP
Protocol: TCP
Port range: 80
Source: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I tried other options in service, nothing worked

```
....
annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"

spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local # Tried both Cluster and Local
....
```

Comment: It means the IP reaching from 1st instance to second is different and is not your loadbalancer IP . Can yo go the pod and and do `curl -s checkip.dyndns.org` to confirm that the IP is same as your Loadbalancer or not.